# How to find all employees working at current time and pick them using Round Robin

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to implement a Employee task assigning application.

I have a Employee Shift Details table in my SQL server Database. I need to select employees in current time and select one employee for a task from a list of employees who are currently in the shift using round robin scheduling

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Shift_Details](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Shift_Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Week_day] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Login_Time] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Logout_Time] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Assignees_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Assignees_Email] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Team_Lead_Email] [varchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am able to select the employees working at current time using the below query

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Shift_Details]
WHERE Week_day = DATEPART(weekday, Dateadd(hh,-5.00,getdate())) and
       ((Logout_Time > Login_Time and 
         DATEPART(HOUR,Dateadd(hh,-5.00,getdate())) >= Login_Time and 
         DATEPART(HOUR,Dateadd(hh,-5.00,getdate())) <= Logout_Time) or
        (Logout_Time < Login_Time and DATEPART(HOUR,Dateadd(hh,-5.00,getdate())) >= Login_Time)
       );
```

This Query outputs this

```
+----+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID | Shift_Type | Week_day | Login_time | Logout_Time | Assignees_Name  |     Assignees_Email      |     Team_Lead_Email      |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | 1st        |        2 |          8 |          18 | John Doe        | johndoe@aol.com          | jimmykimmel@fun.com      |
|  7 | 2nd        |        2 |         12 |          21 | Noah Arc        | Noaharc@aol.com          | jimmykimmel@fun.com      |
| 11 | 3rd        |        2 |         15 |          24 | John Everyman   | johneveryman@gmail.com   | BodrumSalvador@yahoo.com |
| 16 | 2nd        |        2 |         12 |          21 | Theodore Handle | theodorehandle@yahoo.com | BodrumSalvador@yahoo.com |
| 21 | 3rd        |        2 |         15 |          24 | Sue Shei        | SueShei@dxc.com          | jimmykimmel@fun.com      |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I need only one employee selection at a time using Round Robin. Can I do this inside the SQL server itself ?